# How to select a word from a string containing a specific character or symbol in PHP?

Tags: php

I want to get all the usernames from a post and send them notification.

The post may look like this.

```
Congratulations 
@user1 
@user2 
@user3 
You have won!
```

I want to select all words from the above string that contains `@` symbol and store them as elements of an array so I can use them individually to send a notification to them.

I am using the following code but it gives only on 1 user. How do I get the rest of them?

```
<?php
$post = "Congratulations 
@user1
@user2
@user2
You have won!";
if (strpos($post, "@")) {
$fetch = explode("@", $post);
$show = explode("\r\n", $fetch[1]);
$users = count($show);

foreach ($show as $value) {
    echo "$value <br>";
}
echo "<br>Total $users users.";
}
?>
```

**UPDATE:**

I tried to get the users as suggested by @Pharaoh

```
<?php
$post = "Congratulations 
@user1
@user2
@user2
You have won!";
if (strpos($post, "@")) {
$matches = [];
preg_match_all('/@(\w+)/', $post, $matches);
$users = count($matches);
$matches = array_values($matches);
foreach ($matches as $value) {
    echo "$value <br>";
}
echo "<br>Total $users users.";
}
?>
```

It gives two arrays as output as below.

```
Array 
Array 

Total 2 users.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

I would do this with regular expressions:

```
$matches = [];
preg_match_all('/@(\w+)/', $post, $matches);
var_dump($matches);
```

That way, your usernames don't need to be at the start of a line:

```
This is a sentence with @user1 in the middle.
```

You can see it in action here: https://eval.in/847703
(In case of an error, reload. Eval.in currently seems to have problems)

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate each row and check if the row starts with a `@` or not:

```
$post = "Congratulations 
@user1
@user2
@user2
You have won!";

// Explode the rows on line break
$rows  = explode("\n", $post);

// Create a new empty array where we can store all the users
$users = [];

foreach ($rows as $row) {
    // Check if the current row starts with a @
    if (strpos($row, '@') === 0) {
        // Trim away the @ from the start and push the username to the users array
        $users[] = ltrim($row, '@');
    }
}

var_dump($users);
```

Answer (score 0):

one way for  get sub strings use  regex (PHP Regular Expressions).
in this case :

```
$post = "Congratulations 
@user1
@user2
@user2
You have won!";
$usernames=preg_grep("/^@[\w\d]+/", explode("\n", $post));
```

and you can try in [here](http://www.phpliveregex.com/)